# How to construct an orthogonal matrix with the elements taken from a uniform distribution?

Tags: random

I want to construct an Orthogonal matrix such that its elements are randomly chosen from a uniform interval $[-r,r]$ in Mathematica. The way I am doing it is by simply constructing a matrix whose elements are chosen at random from the above interval and then using the `Orthogonalize` command to construct the orthogonal matrix. Then I am suitably dividing each element with a constant such that all of them lie in the interval $[-r,r]$. This is a very untidy way to do this, and depending on $r$; I have to keep changing the constant to ensure that all the elements lie within the interval, is there a better way to implement it?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[5]]`, see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircularRealMatrixDistribution.html).

Comment: @user293787 this seems fine, but what if I also want that all the elements of the resulting matrix lie in the interval $[-r,r]$?

Comment: If the default is to generate values in the range [-1,1], can't you just use r as a scaling factor?

Comment: I am so sorry but I am just clueless. I tried to rescale all the elements by $r$ but then the resulting matrix wasn't orthogonal anymore. I don't know how to rescale it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. If your original matrix was orthogonal over [-1,1], scaling will result in the output being r * IdentityMatrix, which isn't orthogonal, as you observed.

Comment: But, are you certain the procedure you're using doesn't suffer a similar problem, by running OrthogonalMatrixQ on the result? I tried your procedure out, and found that after the final step to force elements into [-r,r], the matrix failed OrthogonalMatrixQ for a similar reason - the determinant of the original matrix (1) is no longer unity.

Comment: Yes. My bad, I realized that after reading your comment. So what is the way out now ? I was wondering is there a way to construct the matrix from scratch?

Comment: @Erosannin First of all, there are likely to be restrictions on possible r values. I.e. if you dot a row/column vector with itself, it needs to evaluate to 1. This may not be possible if r is too small. Each matrix element is coupled to other elements in its row/column, so there will be constraints on successive elements in order to insure they sum to 1. I.e. if first term is 1/2, the other terms must sum to 3/4. The other option is to use the method in the first comment in a loop, and only exit the loop when your other condition on [-r,r] is met. Probably not the answer you were hoping for.

Comment: @jdp na that was helpful in a way. Thanks for your help.